# how to count elements inside a collect() list and use that count() for a WHERE condition

Tags: neo4j, cypher, aggregate-functions

hope to get some help.

having the following query:

```
MATCH  (a:Academy)-[]-(w:Work)
RETURN collect(distinct a.name)as Associated_academies_for_this_book,w.shortTitle as  
       book_short_title, w.workId as Book_ID order by size(collect(distinct a.name)) desc
```

with this output:
[result query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KO8Jb.png)

i need to return only results having more than 1 element inside lists of first column (the column generated by collect(distinct a.name)),i tried with count(collect)>1 and something similar but didn't manage to have what i need.
Any ideas?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `size`

```
MATCH (a:Academy)-[]-(w:Work)
WITH collect(distinct a.name) as Associated_academies_for_this_book, w.shortTitle as book_short_title, w.WorkID as Book_ID 
WHERE size(Associated_academies_for_this_book)>1
RETURN book_short_title, Book_ID
```

or

You can use `count` [as referenced in](https://neo4j.com/docs/getting-started/current/cypher-intro/results/#cypher-intro-results-collecting-aggregation) the documentation, the aggregate works with `*` and that should give you the occurrences.

```
MATCH (a:Academy)-[]-(w:Work)
WITH collect(distinct a.name) as Associated_academies_for_this_book, 
     w.shortTitle as book_short_title, w.workId as Book_ID, count (*) as occ
WHERE occ>1
RETURN occ, Associated_academies_for_this_book, book_short_title, Book_ID
```

The second one stores this information as `occ` variable with other relevant columns in `WITH` statement as an intermediary step and you can use it if needed later on/in the `RETURN` statement. You can do either with `size` or `count` aggregates.